# Is it possible for a Java source file to run arbitrary code when compiled?

Tags: java, javac

Is it possible for me to structure a Java source file such that, when compiled with `javac` (but not invoked with `java`) it will run arbitrary code?

Or can I assume that it's safe to run arbitrary source files through `javac`?

Comment: I would put my money on the "it's safe" answer. If it's not safe to do this, then that's a security hole in `javac`.

Comment: @MattBall: has such a security hole ever existed?

Comment: Couldn't say, off the top of my head. Java's been around for a long time and is a _huge_ code base which has gone through drastic changes.

Comment: I know of no such "hole", but I wouldn't bet my life that there isn't one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never actually used this feature, but javac can run annotation processors -- which I believe are jut arbitrary code. The processors have to be in the processor path, which by default is just the user class path. So depending on your use case, I think that yes, this is a security concern to watch out for. You'll probably want to make sure annotation processing is disabled with `-proc:none`, or take some other precaution.

See the [Annotation Processing section of the Javac manual](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for `javac` to execute Java, regardless of how the source files are set up.  All it is going to do is compile java files into class files.